# Can I header redirect to mutiple URL's or use a variable to do so?

Tags: php, redirect

Here is what I want to do. At the moment I have 3 sign up pages. 2 for affiliates and 1 for members who happens to wonder into the site. The issue I had was that when the affiliates would send members if the members left their join form and ended up at the main join form for the site which is my join form...then the affiliates would not get credit for the sale.

To fix this I created a cookie on the two affiliate join forms. Now if they visit the affiliate join form first...the cookie is created...then if they wonder the site and end up clicking the Register link for my join form...it redirects them to the affiliates join for that they came to the site on.

This works fine but I have no way to make both join forms redirect without getting the "header already sent" message.

What I have is this:

```
<?php // find the ip address cookie, if its set, redirect
if (isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress"])) {
    // redirect
    header ('Location: usersignupcredit.php');
} 
?>
<?php echo((isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress"]))?$_COOKIE["ipaddress"]:"") ?>
```

What I need is something like this that works

```
<?php // find the ip address cookie, if its set, redirect
if (isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress"])) {
    // redirect
    header ('Location: page1.php');
}
if (isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress2"])) {
    // redirect
    header ('Location: page2.php');
?>
<?php echo((isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress"]))?$_COOKIE["ipaddress"]:"") ?>
```

So it would look for both cookies ipaddress and ipaddress2

If ipaddress is found then it would send to page1.php
If ipaddress2 is found then it would send to page2.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: redirect header ('Location: usersignupcredit.php

usersignupcredit.php would be page1.php in this example

Comment: Does the above code not work? What does it do? How does this vary from what you want?

Comment: Just a note, according to the HTTP protocol, a Location header is supposed to have an absolute URL, not a relative one.  So; `header("Location: http://example.com/page1");`

Comment: can you not just create another php file for "ONLY header redirects" with no output? this way every time the users must go through the redirect page, you can make conditional statements without output, and send em off to wherever they need to be?

Comment: Jon & Michael, the code actually works but when it goes to the 2nd URL there is not issues but when they are redirected to the fist URL I get the header already sent and that is because of what Micheal said "a Location header is supposed to have an absolute URL, not a relative one" So yea it actually does redirect to the page but I get that error at the top of the page.

robx can you tell me more about the php file with ONLY header redirects...that may be the way to go for me...maybe point me in the right direction...please and thank you.

Comment: Jon, ok i get it. I would change the Header Redirect to say redirect.php so then if the cookie is there...they will get directed to the redirect.php. From there I would send them to either page 1 or page 2. 

Now my questions is...how do I send them to page 1 or page 2?

Comment: Actually this code is what worked for me:

`code`

<?php // find the ip address cookie, if its set, redirect
if (isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress"])) {
// redirect
header ('Location: usersignupcredit.php');
exit();
}
else
if (isset($_COOKIE["ipaddress2"])) {
// redirect
header ('Location: usersignupnew.php');
exit();
}
?>

`code`

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about the design for a second - why do you need to have 3 forms? Isn't it cleaner to just have 1 form and take the affiliate variable through GET and store that in a cookie?

For example, a member visits your page through `/join.php?aff=<aff-id>`, the affiliate with aff-id gets credited for the signup. If a member visits your page simply as /join.php, nobody gets credit.

Seems simpler and more straight-forward if you ask me.

PS: If you don't want `?aff` to mean the obvious, rename it to some obscure variable, most regular users won't even notice it.

Comment: The affiliate company wanted more control of creating affiliate accounts. So in order not to let the affiliate in my main account I had to create sub accounts. So the JOIN form that I use would actually not register the affiliate sale because I have no affiliates directly under that main account. Only the sub account form has affiliates. So even if I pass variables to the main JOIN form...only I would get credit. 

I use 2 affiliate forms because one is for a $4.99 trial that rebills at $39.99 after 24 hours and the other form is for an instant bill for $50.99 that rebills in 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive a `headers already sent` message, the most likely problem is that your are outputting stuff to the browser before the `header` command. You need to make sure that you don't echo anything or have any spaces or new-lines outside of your php tags before the part where you use `header`.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to use 2 header commands and I can only use 1. Although the redirection actually works with 2 header commands...when I redirect to the first Header I always get that Header already sent error...that is because I am putting information after the first header redirect and the information I am putting is the second header redirect...am I confusing you? Cuz I am almost confusing me :)